# Message: unknown error: cannot parse internal JSON template: Line: 1, column: 1, Unexpected token

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, chromium

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\jack_l\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data")
options.add_argument(r'--profile-directory=Profile 8')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
```

I'm getting the `Message: unknown error: cannot parse internal JSON template: Line: 1, column: 1, Unexpected token.` error at the `driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)` line. I found another post saying they fixed the problem by deleting their entire Chrome folder and reinstalling ([Python Selenium Chrome - Message: unknown error: cannot parse internal JSON template: Line: 1, column: 1, Unexpected token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72133754/python-selenium-chrome-message-unknown-error-cannot-parse-internal-json-temp)), but would anyone else know an alternative to that? And just out of curiosity; what would deleting the chrome folder do anyway (my chrome accounts are synced)

This error popped out of no where btw, like the program was running fine this morning, then i boot it up again a few hours later and I get this (I havent changed anything).

Full Error:

```
Exception has occurred: WebDriverException
Message: unknown error: cannot parse internal JSON template: Line: 1, column: 1, Unexpected token.
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    Ordinal0 [0x00A7B8F3+2406643]
    Ordinal0 [0x00A0AF31+1945393]
    Ordinal0 [0x008FC748+837448]
    Ordinal0 [0x0091B4CF+963791]
    Ordinal0 [0x0091B7C5+964549]
    Ordinal0 [0x009192B6+955062]
    Ordinal0 [0x00915D71+941425]
    Ordinal0 [0x00948EE0+1150688]
    Ordinal0 [0x00948B3A+1149754]
    Ordinal0 [0x00944096+1130646]
    Ordinal0 [0x0091E636+976438]
    Ordinal0 [0x0091F546+980294]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00CE9612+2498066]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00CDC920+2445600]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00B14F2A+579370]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x00B13D36+574774]
    Ordinal0 [0x00A11C0B+1973259]
    Ordinal0 [0x00A16688+1992328]
    Ordinal0 [0x00A16775+1992565]
    Ordinal0 [0x00A1F8D1+2029777]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x75F4FA29+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77657A7E+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77657A4E+238]
  File "C:\Users\jack_l\Documents\BEATSTARS_PYTHON_SELENIUM\uploadToBeatstars.py", line 34, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
```

Picture of full error:
[image]

Comment: Please show a [complete](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146) error message.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I added the entire error now. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Weird. You're certain that you don't see a message that starts with `Traceback (most recent call last):`?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I added a picture of the full error to my original post. Isn't that the entire error – could I be missing something? I'm using VSCode.

Comment: I haven't seen one look like that before. I don't know if it's because your IDE is trying to format things differently, but it does suggest that something is happening in internal code written in a language other than Python. The obvious underlying cause is that some file somewhere is not valid JSON when it's expected to be - since the problem is detected at the very beginning of the file, it probably isn't JSON at all, or is empty or something like that. But I was hoping the error traceback would help to figure out *which* file.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48571886/webdriverexception-when-starting-chromedriver-with-user-data-dir-argument) help? I found it by coping and pasting the error message into a general-purpose search engine (not by using Stack Overflow's search, which unfortunately is often not very good).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Is that forum just saying to delete those two files? Because when I go and manually delete the two files they're talking about I still get the same error.

Comment: Per the other question, what helped for me was fixing the permissions of the profile directory: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74702107/435093

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get it up and running again! The solution that worked for me was deleting C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome folder and reinstalling Chrome. If you run into this problem, give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

I solved by deleting the folder .config. In my particular case I use this custom path:

```
self.options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=.config/google-chrome")
```

Comment: just a note: do not delete folder _.config_, but folder _.config/google-chrome_

Answer (score 0):

After running into this same problem, I was able to restore Chrome's default settings to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

In my case my disk was running out of storage so i cleaned it.

Comment: If it is about out of disk space then, you have to launch Chrome manually to allow it to create necessary files again. Otherwise, it will keep prompting errors. 

Just relaunch Chrome manually before reinstalling it.

Answer (score 0):

The same issue happened to me.

I tried the 'Repair' function in "Programs and Features". It redownloads and reinstalls MSEdge.

After the installation, the default profile of MSEdge is overwritten, so the relevant settings and extensions are **RESET**.

Luckily, my selenium configuration uses several other profiles, other than the default. The browser preference settings and installed extensions remain untouched.

Answer (score 0):

The same issue happened to me.I fixed this by uninstall then install again chrome then my selenium script now no more thrown "**cannot parse internal JSON template"** error